# PDF page navigation issue

Tags: android, pdf, android-pdf-api, androidpdfviewer

As per the SO recommendations, I am using following library to render PDF file. https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

This pdf contains link to redirect to pages. First page is like index. It has list of link to navigate to a particular page of PDF.

But onlick of any link nothing is happening.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is [not implemented](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/357).

The workaround is to parse PDF file ([manually](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) or using any third party library), extract link annotations and handle link navigation manually.